# Is there a good notion of higher-rank archimedean norm?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, norms, valuation-theory, valuation-rings

Let $K$ be a field. I think I know what a norm (archimedean or not) $|-| : K \to \mathbb R_{\geq 0}$ is. In the case where the norm is nonarchimedean, it's equivalent to the data of a valuation of rank 1 $v : K \to \mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$. There is also a notion of higher rank valuations, which are always nonarchimedean in nature.

**Question:** Is there a good notion of higher-rank archimedean norm?

If so, where can I read about it?

Comment: I suppose you could define a more general type of norm on $K$ as a map $|\cdot|: K \longrightarrow L_{\geq 0}$, where $L$ is an ordered field.  Usually $L = \mathbb{R}$ is taken as it is a terminal object in the category of archimedean ordered fields, so "higher-rank archimedean norm" doesn't seem to be a thing unless maybe you consider rings $K$ with zerodivisors.  If you take $L$ to be the ordered (proper-class) field No of all surreal numbers, then maybe look at the image of $K$ in No to find some notion of rank?