# Higher-rank Archimedean valuations of $\mathbb{Q}$, does it exist?

Tags: nt.number-theory, norms, valuation-theory, berkovich-geometry, valuation-rings

I was reading the proof of Ostrowski's theorem, with an eye toward the Zariski-Riemann space (as well as adic space, Berkovich space, etc.) In the proof, the value group is always assumed to be in $\mathbb{R}^{\times}$ for ease of using logarithms and exponentials, especially in the Archimedean valuations part. I suspect that the value group can't have a higher-rank than $1$ because "$\mathbb{Q}$ is a 1-dimensional object," but I'm unsure how to prove this.

**Claim(Ostrowski):** Every non-trivial soft valuation on the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ is equivalent to either the usual real absolute value or a $p$-adic absolute value.

I'd also like to understand the classification of soft valuations on $\mathbb{C}_p(t)$, preferably with a proof.

---

Since the notion of valuation varies in different references, let me clarify my definitions for this question:

- Let $R$ be a ring.
- A **soft valuation** of $R$ is a map
  $$|\cdot|_v: R \longrightarrow \Gamma$$
  where $\Gamma$ is an ordered (commutative) semiring (with $1$), with $0 \in \Gamma$ minimal, such that

  - $|0|_v =0, |1|_v =1;$
  - $|ab|_v=|a|_v \cdot |b_v|;$
  - $|a+b|_v \leqslant |a|_v + |b|_v;$
- We say $|\cdot|_v$ **is equivalent to** $|\cdot|_{v'} $, when there exist $|\cdot|_{v_0}: R \longrightarrow \Gamma_0$, maps of semirings (as an ordered monoid homomorphism for the multiplication structure) $\Gamma_0 \longrightarrow \Gamma$, $\Gamma_0 \longrightarrow \Gamma'$, such that the diagram

[image: the commutative diagram of equivalence of valuations]

$\qquad$ commutes.

- We say $|\cdot|_v$ is **NA**(Non-Archimedean), if
  $$|a+b|_v \leqslant \max \big\{ |a|_v,|b_v| \big\} \qquad \text{ for any } a,b \in R.$$
  Otherwise, we say that $|\cdot|_v$ is **Archimedean**.
- The **trivial valuation**
  $$|\cdot|_{triv}: R \longrightarrow \{ 0,1 \} \qquad x \neq 0 \longmapsto 1$$
  is defined to be of rank $0$.

$\qquad$Any soft valuation with $\Gamma= \mathbb{R}_{\geqslant 0}$ is defined to be of rank $1$.

$\qquad$If the soft valuation $|\cdot|_v$ is not equivalent to rank $0,1$ soft valuations mentioned above, then we call that $|\cdot|_v$ has **higher ranks**.

---

**Related and refered:**

The proof of classical Ostrowski's theorem: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrowski%27s_theorem)

Similar questions with no real answer:

- [Generalization of Ostrowski's Theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/343853/generalization-of-ostrowskis-theorem)
- [Is there a good notion of higher-rank archimedean norm?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309712/valuation-with-values-in-a-semiring)
- [Valuation with values in a semiring?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444974/is-there-a-good-notion-of-higher-rank-archimedean-norm) (I'm uncertain whether $\Gamma$ can be embedded into an Archimedean ordered field when $|\cdot|_v$ is Archimedean. [Proposition 5 in kahen's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11923/completion-of-rational-numbers-via-cauchy-sequences) and [the discussion here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76222/is-mathbb-r-terminal-among-archimedean-fields) might provide some insight.)

[Ostrowski's Theorem for topological rings?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311047/ostrowskis-theorem-for-topological-rings) (quoted for fun and completeness, though our question don't consider topological rings)

Comment: Is “soft valuation” a standard term? Is there somewhere I can read about these?

Comment: No, "soft valuation" is not a standard term. I come up with this terminology myself to avoid the confusion with Bourbaki's definition of (NA) valuations, and you can also call it as "generalized valuation" or by any other name you prefer. The use of "soft" suggests that this definition is flexible enough to specializing to various types of valuations. It is concise while still avoiding everyday language confusion. If you have suggestions for a more suitable term, please feel free to share them here.

Comment: In addition to the links I provided, you can find definitions of NA valuations with higher rank for adic spaces in [Berkeley notes, Definition 2.3.1](https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Berkeley.pdf). The multiplicative seminorm is defined for Berkovich spaces, see [introduction to Berkovich analytic spaces ...](https://swc-math.github.io/aws/2007/BakerNotesMarch21.pdf). While it's likely that others have also systematically studied these "soft valuations", I don't have any exact reference to provide.

Comment: It seems to me that according to the given definition, the archimedean valuations $|x|^\alpha$ for $0<\alpha\le1$ (which normally count as equivalent in Ostrowski's theorem) are not equivalent. Or do I misunderstand what "morphism of semirings" means?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thanks for your correction. I should only require that morphisms preserve semigroup structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following valuation:

$|\cdot|:\mathbb{Q}\to[0,\infty)^\mathbb{N}$ defined as
$|q|=(|q|_{p_i})_i$ where $(p_i)_i$
is the increasing sequence of all the prime numbers and $|\cdot|_{p_i}$ is the $p_i$-adic valuation on $\mathbb{Q}$.

Here, $|\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}|\subset(0,\infty)^\mathbb{N}$ is an ordered group with the component-wise multiplication and the lexicographic order. Furthermore, $[0,\infty)^\mathbb{N}$ is a semiring if we also consider the component-wise addition.
Since the topology induced by this valuation on $\mathbb{Q}$ is equivalent to the one induced by $|\cdot|_2$, then according to the definition given on this question, this is a rank 1 valuation.

Comment: That's a nice example! Some minor points:
$\tag*{}$
- $|\mathbb{Q}\smallsetminus\{0\}|\neq(0,\infty)^\mathbb{N}$.
$\tag*{}$
- According to the definition of ordered semiring in the first answer of [\[this question\]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539318/about-definition-of-ordered-semi-ring), $[0,\infty)^\mathbb{N}$ is not an ordered semiring. $(0,\infty)^\mathbb{N} \sqcup \{0\}$ is.
$\tag*{}$
- What does the NA order mean?

Comment: The topology induced by this valuation is identical to the one induced by the $2$-adic valuation (assuming the “lexicographic order” puts the $2$-component first).

Comment: @zxx You are right that the value group is different than the proposed codomain. I've corrected that. Also, you are right, the proposed codomain is not an ordered semiring according to the mentioned definition. NA order is one in which there are 2 nonzero elements $x$ and $y$ such that $nx<y$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. For example, in $[0,\infty)^2$ the lexicographic order is  NA because $n(0,1)=(0,n)<(1,0)$  for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination of the NA order. I think that  for $(0,\infty)^\mathbb{N} \sqcup \{0\}$, the lexicographic order is not NA. Therefore, the example you found is an **Archimedean** valuation of higher rank, with valued group lying in an **Archimedean** ordered semiring.

Answer (score -1):

**Corrected Answer:** Yes, there are Archimedean valuations of $\mathbb{Q}$ of higher-rank.
Consider $F$ the field of fractions of the ring of polynomials with real exponents. This is, $F=\Big\lbrace{\dfrac{a_1x^{r_1}+\cdots a_nx^{r_n}}{b_1x^{s_1}+\cdots b_nx^{s_m}}:r_i,s_i\in\mathbb{R} , \mbox{not all $b_i$ are zero}\Big\rbrace}$. Here $x^0=1_F$.

$F$ is an ordered field with: $a_1x^{r_1}+\cdots a_nx^{r_n}>0$ iff $a_n>0$ (here $n$ is chosen such that $r_n=max\{r_i:a_i\neq0\}$). For $P(x)=a_1x^{r_1}+\cdots a_nx^{r_n}$ and $Q(x)=b_1x^{s_1}+\cdots b_nx^{s_m}$, then $P<Q$ iff $0<Q-P$.
Finally, $\dfrac{P(x)}{Q(x)}>0$ iff $P(x)Q(x)>0$.

**The higher-rank valuation:** Consider
$|\cdot|_v:\mathbb{Q}\to F$ defined by $|0|_v=0$ and $|q|_v=x^{\log_2|q|_2}$ for $q\neq0$, where $|2^nr|_2=2^{-n}$ (with $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ whose numerator and denominator are coprime to $2$) is the 2-adic valuation on $\mathbb{Q}$.

By straightforward verification:

- $|0|_v =0, |1|_v =1;$
- $|ab|_v=|a|_v \cdot |b|_v;$
- $|a+b|_v \leqslant |a|_v + |b|_v;$

Just in case, I will show that $|\cdot|_v$ satisfies the strong triangular inequality:

In the particular case that $a=-b\neq0$, we have $|a+b|_v=0<x^{\log_2|a|_2}$.

In the case that $a\neq -b$, we have that the $2$-adic valuation satisfies the non-Archimedean triangle inequality:

$$ |a+b|_2 \leq \max(|a|_2, |b|_2) $$

Taking the logarithm of each side (for $a$ and $b$ not both zero) of this inequality, and since the logarithm function is monotonic, you'd have:

$$ \log_2 |a+b|_2 \leq \log_2 \max(|a|_2, |b|_2)  = \max(\log_2 |a|_2, \log_2 |b|_2) $$

$$ x^{\log_2 |a+b|_2} \leq x^{\max(\log_2 |a|_2, \log_2 |b|_2)} $$

And so:

$$ |a+b|_v = x^{\log_2 |a+b|_2} \leq \max(x^{\log_2 |a|_2}, x^{\log_2 |b|_2}) = \max(|a|_v, |b|_v). $$

$F$ is non-Archimedean and therefore, it cannot be embedded in $\mathbb{R}$. Indeed, $n\cdot 1_F<x$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

In conclusion, $|\cdot|_v$ is of higher-rank.

Comment: Do you know why $\Gamma$ must satisfy the Archimedean property, and why $\Gamma$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: If there are rational numbers $p$ and $q$ such that |np|<|q| for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then you will get a contradiction. Also, an ordered ring satisfying the Archimedean property can be embedded into the real numbers is a well-known result in abstract algebra and real analysis. A detailed proof of this statement can be found in “Algebra” by Michael Artin.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your argument. If you take $p=0$ and $q=1$, I don't see any contradiction. I also couldn't find any proof or statement about ordered fields in the reference you mentioned. I would appreciate it if you could provide a more detailed argument and specify the exact location in the reference, rather than the entire book.

Comment: For your new answer: if you take $a=3$, $b=-2$, then
$$|a+b|_v=1>x^{-\ln 3} + x^{- \ln 2} = |a|_v+|b|_v.$$

Comment: I see. In that case, let's adjust the exponent and use $\ln|q|$ instead of $-\ln|q|$.

Comment: If you adjust the exponent, take $a=1$, $b=2$, then
$$|a+b|_v=x^{\ln 3}>1+x^{\ln 2}=|a|_v+|b|_v.$$

Comment: I can't make sense of the definition of order on $F$. Are the exponents meant to be ordered as $r_1<\dots<r_n$ or $r_1>\dots>r_n$? Either way, why are you separating out the $x^0$ term? As written the definition makes all three of $x$, $-1+x$ and $-1+x^{-1}$ positive, which is impossible. It appears you want $x$ to be infinitesimal and infinite at the same time.

Comment: Though it does not really matter: whether $x$ is infinitesinal or infinitely large, one of zxx's examples shows that the triangle inequality fails.

Comment: @zxx I've corrected the valuation so now satisfies the triangular inequality.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek you are right. I have specified the definition of the order in $F$ so now it is clearer.

Comment: The valuation as defined now is equivalent to $|x|_2$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Indeed, one of higher rank equivalent to $|\cdot|_2$.

Comment: Please, read carefully the question. A valuation is defined to be of higher rank here if it is *not equivalent* to a valuation of rank 0 or 1 (i.e., one of the standard valuations from Ostrowski’s theorem). Thus, your valuation is *not* of higher rank, and it does not answer the question. It is indeed trivial to construct valuations equivalent to the standard ones with values in nonarchimedean fields, but that’s besides the point as it does not say anything about the truth of the generalization of Ostrowski’s theorem considered in the question.